# Extract ratings and corresponding dates from text in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract ratings and their dates for each bank from the data frame. Also, make the individual rating records to new rows and separate the ratings and dates into two columns.

Here is my data sample:

```
mydf <- data.frame("bank_name"=c("Bank A","Bank B"), "records"=c("Rating: B-\nRating Range: Jun-08-2017 to Present\n\nRating: B\nRating Range: Jan-23-2013 to Jun-08-2017","Rating: BBB-\nRating Range: Oct-02-2018 to Present\n\nRating: B\nRating Range: Apr-06-2018 to Oct-02-2018\n\nRating: A\nRating Range: Jun-08-2007 to Jan-31-2008\n\nRating: CCC\nRating Range: Jan-23-2006 to Aug-08-2007"))
```

Here is what I expect:

```
mydf2 <- data.frame("bank_name"=c("Bank A","Bank A","Bank B","Bank B","Bank B","Bank B"), "ratings"=c("B-","B","BBB-","B","A","CCC"),"date"=c("Jun-08-2017","Jan-23-2013","Oct-02-2018","Apr-06-2018","Jun-08-2007","Jan-23-2006"))

> mydf2
  bank_name ratings        date
1    Bank A    B-     Jun-08-2017
2    Bank A    B      Jan-23-2013
3    Bank B    BBB-   Oct-02-2018
4    Bank B    B      Apr-06-2018
5    Bank B    A      Jun-08-2007
6    Bank B    CCC    Jan-23-2006
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to extract the characters after the 'Rating', 'Rating Range' in 'records' column with `str_extract_all` into a `list` and `unnest` the `list` elements

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(ratings = str_extract_all(records, "(?<=Rating: )[A-E-]+"), 
         date = str_extract_all(records, 
              "(?<=Rating Range: )[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) %>% 
  select(-records) %>%
  unnest
#  bank_name ratings        date
#1    Bank A      B- Jun-08-2017
#2    Bank A       B Jan-23-2013
#3    Bank B    BBB- Oct-02-2018
#4    Bank B       B Apr-06-2018
#5    Bank B       A Jun-08-2007
#6    Bank B     CCC Jan-23-2006
```

Comment: It works! One thing to mention is that I added a "+" sign in [A-E-] for possible + sign in ratings. (There is no such as A+ in my sample data but a rating could contain + at the end). I'm not sure if it is the correct place to add +, but it works!

Comment: @OllieMa  You can add it in `[A-E-+]+`

Comment: Cool! I really appreciate your help  @akrun